# median of the two sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was not able to understand the below base case 5 and 6 for calculating the median of two sorted arrays. N and M are the two array length.

Base cases:
The smaller array has only one element

> Case 0: N = 0, M = 2
>
> Case 1: N = 1, M = 1.
>
> Case 2: N = 1, M is odd
>
> Case 3: N = 1, M is even

The smaller array has only two elements

> Case 4: N = 2, M = 2
>
> Case 5: N = 2, M is odd
>
> Case 6: N = 2, M is even

Case 0: There are no elements in first array, return median of second array. If second array is also empty, return -1.

Case 1: There is only one element in both arrays, so output the average of A[0] and B[0].

Case 2: N = 1, M is odd
Let B[5] = {5, 10, 12, 15, 20}
First find the middle element of B[], which is 12 for above array. There are following 4 sub-cases.

> …2.1 If A[0] is smaller than 10, the median is average of 10 and 12.
>
> …2.2 If A[0] lies between 10 and 12, the median is average of A[0] and
>   12.
>
> …2.3 If A[0] lies between 12 and 15, the median is average of 12 and
>   A[0].
>
> …2.4 If A[0] is greater than 15, the median is average of 12 and 15.

In all the sub-cases, we find that 12 is fixed. So, we need to find the median of B[ M / 2 – 1 ], B[ M / 2 + 1], A[ 0 ] and take its average with B[ M / 2 ].

Case 3: N = 1, M is even

Let B[4] = {5, 10, 12, 15}

First find the middle items in B[], which are 10 and 12 in above example. There are following 3 sub-cases.

> …3.1 If A[0] is smaller than 10, the median is 10.
>
> …3.2 If A[0] lies between 10 and 12, the median is A[0].
>
> …3.3 If A[0] is greater than 12, the median is 12.

So, in this case, find the median of three elements B[ M / 2 – 1 ], B[ M / 2] and A[ 0 ].

Case 4: N = 2, M = 2
There are four elements in total. So we find the median of 4 elements.

Case 5: N = 2, M is odd

Let B[5] = {5, 10, 12, 15, 20}

The median is given by median of following three elements: B[M/2], max(A[0], B[M/2 – 1]), min(A[1], B[M/2 + 1]).

Case 6: N = 2, M is even

Let B[4] = {5, 10, 12, 15}

The median is given by median of following four elements: B[M/2], B[M/2 – 1], max(A[0], B[M/2 – 2]), min(A[1], B[M/2 + 1])

I was referring the below URL for understanding the median of two sorted arrays.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays-of-different-sizes/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to see how this works is ... with a pencil and paper. *Draw* two lists of numbers *(both short ...)*, one with an odd number of elements, the other even.  Now, look very carefully at the slight-but-important differences between the solutions for Case 5 *vs.* Case 6.

Since the logic as-presented uses the `MAX()` function several times, with your pencil-and-paper construct situations where first one, then the other of the two parameters to `MAX()` are "biggest."

In fifteen minutes or so with that piece of paper and that number-two pencil, you'll be able to convince yourself that the algorithm does *(or, doesn't?)* work.

... *(and, yeah, this is a perfectly serious recommendation. This is **exactly** how I work such things out!)*